# Is there a way to use a short circuit operator silently in vimscript?

Tags: vim

How should I load colorscheme so that I can use `lucius` colorscheme only on my local machine?

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2536

This colorscheme declares a few functions to change color styles.  So I tried to write my setting as following not to harm remote environment that using same `vimrc` file:

```
silent! colorscheme lucius | LuciusBlackHighContrast
```

But it seems like the `silent!` always returns success, it turns out the line giving me an error: `E492: Not an editor command:  LuciusBlackHighContrast`.

I just wanted to make it like: `colorscheme lucius >/dev/null && LuciusBlackHighContrast`.

All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The bar is just a separator, not a boolean operator; and both `colorscheme` and `silent!` are commands, not returning any value. This is not `bash` :)</strike> Try this:

```
let v:errmsg = ""
silent! colorscheme lucius
if v:errmsg == ""
  LuciusBlackHighContrast
endif
```

Comment: Thank you! But `:help :bar` even says `Note that when the command before the '|' generates an error, the following commands will not be executed.` and I thought somehow I can use it as '&&'. In other words, I'm looking for the way to generate errors silently.

Comment: @ernix: Oh, you're correct! :) Then this must be tripping you up: "When [!] is added, error messages will also be skipped, and commands and mappings will not be aborted when an error is detected." In other words, skipping errors is really skipping errors. However, "`v:errmsg` is still set." (From `:help silent`)